# Can someone solve my non-understandable process in proving a theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

### Theorem.

Let $E$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Then, if $p\gt0$, $\int_E|f-f_k|^p\to0$, and $\displaystyle\int_E|f_k|^p\le{}M$ for all $k$, then $\displaystyle\int_E|f|^p\le{}M$.

For your information, $|\cdot|$ means a Lebesgue measure.

---

- There is a **Theorem A**, $$\int_E|f|^p=p\int_0^\infty\alpha^{p-1}w_{|f|}(\alpha)d\alpha$$
  ,where $w(\alpha)=\left|\left(\mathbf{x}\in{}E:f(\mathbf{x})\gt\alpha\right\}\right|$
- Since $|f|\le|f-f_k|+|f_k|$ by the triangle inequality,
  $$\int_E|f|\le\int_E\left(|f-f_k|+|f_k|\right)=\int_E|f-f_k|+\int_E|f_k|$$
- From the **Theorem A** when $p=1$,
  $$\int_0^\infty w_{|f|}(\alpha)d\alpha \le \int_0^\infty w_{|f-f_k|}(\alpha)d\alpha + \int_0^\infty w_{|f_k|}(\alpha)d\alpha$$
- Since (?),
  $$w_{|f|}(\alpha) \le w_{|f-f_k|}(\alpha) + w_{|f_k|}(\alpha)$$
- Thus,
  \begin{align}
  \int_E|f|^p &= p\int_0^\infty\alpha^{p-1}w_{|f|}(\alpha)d\alpha \\
  &\le p\int_0^\infty\alpha^{p-1}\left(w_{|f-f_k|}(\alpha) + w_{|f_k|}(\alpha)\right)d\alpha \\
  &= p\int_0^\infty\alpha^{p-1} w_{|f-f_k|}(\alpha) d\alpha + p\int_0^\infty\alpha^{p-1} w_{|f_k|}(\alpha) d\alpha \\
  &=\int_E|f-f_k|^p + \int_E|f_k|^p
  \end{align}
- Letting $k\to\infty$,
  $$\int_E|f|^p \le M$$

---

I do not understand how the third process causes the fourth process.

Also, I do not understand the last process.

We are proving that $\displaystyle\int_E|f|^p\le{}M$, not proving that $\displaystyle\int_E|f|^p\le{}M$ as $k\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Since $p >0$, we have that
   $$ |f-g|^p \leq |f|^p + |g|^p $$
2. Using 1, we see
   $$ \int |f|^p dx \leq \int | f- f_k|^p dx + \int |f_k|^p dx $$
   for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$.
3. Apply bound, we see
   $$\int |f|^p dx \leq \int | f- f_k|^p dx + M $$
4. Apply the limit, we see
   $$\int |f|^p dx \leq\underbrace{ \lim_{k \to \infty} \int | f- f_k|^p dx}_{=0}+ M \leq M $$
   as desired.

Comment: Just a small note, $\lim_{k \to\infty} \int|f_k|^p dx$ might not exist, so it would be better to replace that term by $M$ before taking the limit.

Comment: very true, I'll fix it.

Comment: Can I ask the process number four? I don't know why applying limit is fine. We have to show that $\int_E|f|^p\le{}M$. However, if $k$ is not large enough to make the term zero, $\int_E|f|^p\le{}M$ does not hold, does it?

Comment: In step 3, we have that that bound holds for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Thus taking $k$ to be large gives a sharper bound for $f$ since $f_k \to f$ in $L^p$.

Comment: Don't I need to use $w_f(\alpha)$ function?