# If $f_k\overset{m}{\longrightarrow}f$ and and $\int_E |f_k|^p \le M$, then $\int_E |f|^p \le M$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

My question stems from [this post.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1798103/425395) I'd like to show that if $p > 0$, $f_k$ converges to $f$ in measure on $E$, and $\int_E |f_k|^p \le M$ for all $k\ge 1$, then $\int_E |f|^p \le M$.

---

Note that the hypothesis that $f_k$ converges to $f$ in measure is weaker than $\int_E |f_k - f|^p \xrightarrow{k\to\infty} 0$. For example, take $p = 1$. Then, $f_k = k \mathbf{1}_{[0,1/k]}$ converges to $f \equiv 0$ in measure, as $|\{|f_k| > \epsilon\}| = \frac 1 k$ for small enough $\epsilon$. However, $\int_E |f_k| = 1$ for all $k\ge 1$, so $\int_E|f_k - f| \not\to 0$ as $k\to\infty$.

Here's what I have so far:

$$\int_E |f|^p \le \int_E |f_k - f|^p + \int_E |f_k|^p \le M + \int_E |f_k - f|^p$$
and
\begin{align*}
\int_E |f_k - f|^p &= \int_{\{|f_k-f| \le \epsilon\}} |f_k - f|^p + \int_{\{|f_k-f| > \epsilon\}} |f_k - f|^p\\
&\le \epsilon^p |\{|f_k-f| \le \epsilon\}| + \int_{\{|f_k-f| > \epsilon\}} |f_k - f|^p
\end{align*}
Suppose $|E| < \infty$ (hopefully we can deal with $|E| = \infty$ later, by intersecting $E$ with annuli.) Then, $$\int_E |f_k - f|^p \le \epsilon^p |E| + \int_{\{|f_k-f| > \epsilon\}} |f_k - f|^p$$
If I had a bound for $|f_k - f|^p$, I could use that $\lim_{k\to\infty} |\{|f_k-f| > \epsilon\}| = 0$ for every $\epsilon > 0$ (i.e., convergence in measure.) Subsequently, taking $\epsilon \to 0$ would give the result. However, there doesn't seem to be an obvious upper bound on $|f_k - f|^p$, so this technique doesn't work.

Comment: Convegence in measure implies a.e. convergence for a subsequence and Fatou's Lemma finishes the proof.

Comment: It is immediate from Fatou's Lemma.

Comment: Are you clear about the fact that $f_{n_k} \to f$ a.e. implies $|f_{n_k}|^{p} \to |f|^{p}$ a.e. ?  If every term of  a sequence $a_n$ satiafies $a_n \leq M$ doesn't it follows that $\lim \inf a_n \leq M$? It is hard to imagine where your difficulty is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $f_k\overset{m}{\longrightarrow}f$, there is a subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}$ such that $f_{n_k}{\longrightarrow}f$ a.e. in $E$. Then,
$$\int_E |f|^p = \int_E \liminf_{k\to\infty}
 |f_{n_k}|^p \le \liminf_{k\to\infty} \int_E |f_{n_k}|^p \le M$$
Easier than I thought. Thanks @geetha290krm.